# how can i add a text entered in a form show on a div? like on facebook

Tags: html, css, facebook, forms, textbox

how can i enter a word on a textbox in a form then after clicking submit or enter, it would show on the Div the text typed? here is what i have so far:

```
        <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>website</title>
<style>
body {background-color: black;
color: green;
}
#hello { 
border-style:groove; 
border-color: yellow; 
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
width:300px;
}
form {
text-align:center;
margin:auto;
margin-top:300px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="hello">Welcome to here :D</div>

<div id="theirname"></div>

<form action="submit" method="post">
Your name: <input id="textbox" type="text" name="fname" size="20" />
<input type="button" value="post" />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using javascript:

```
function handler() {

  var div = document.getElementById('theirname');

  div.innerHTML = document.getElementById('textbox').value;

  return false;
}
```

You also need to change

```
<input type="button" value="post" />
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="post" />
```

And

```
<form action="submit" id="form" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="submit" id="form" method="post" onsubmit="return handler()">
```

[Demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/2eX7Z/)

Comment: I have added your code to my html, but it doesn't do anything. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Did you add `id` attribute to your `form` tag? Because it is important for script to work.

Comment: I can't really know what's the problem, can you check your error console?

Comment: yes it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onsubmit' of null"

Comment: it takes me to a different page, cant I like make it add it right then and there? I also added the script in the 'head' section, do i have to make a JavaScript page for it or is it fine there?

Comment: There was some weird bug in window.onload, but i changed my post try now.

Comment: It removed the textbox.

Comment: what? There's no code for removing the textbox, can you check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2eX7Z/2/.

Comment: @Mrawesome4ever Is it working now? If it is, please mark my answer accepted by clicking green checkmark above vote count.